# Not Serializable Exception when using Scalaz with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalaz

I made a simple example to try and integrate [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/v7.1.0)  code with Apache Spark 1.5.

Here is a simple Spark program to illustrate my problem:

```
package test

import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

import ca.crim.deti.re.spark.sparkConf
import scalaz._
import scalaz.Scalaz._

object TestSpark {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local")
    val SC = new SparkContext(conf)
    val c = SC.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

    println(func1(c).count) // WORKS
    println(func2(c).count) // DOES NOT WORK.. NotSerializableException
  }

  // WORKS!
  def func1(rdd: RDD[Int]) = {
    rdd.filter { i => f(i, i) }
  }
  // DOES NOT WORK!
  def func2[I: Equal](rdd: RDD[I]) = {
    rdd.filter { i => f(i, i) }
  }

  def f[I: Equal](i1: I, i2: I) = {
    i1 === i2
  }
}
```

I'd like to make `func2` work by using `Equal` in the function definition.

When executing on Spark environnement in local mode with `func2`, I get the following exception:

[image: Spark environnement exception when using scalaz]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your function has an `Equal[I]` constraint, Spark is closing over that and trying to serialize it when doing the distribution. Since the `scalaz.Equal` type class is not `Serializable` (https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.0/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Equal.scala#L10) Spark fails at runtime with this.

You may be able to get around the fact it's not `Serialziable` by using `MeatLocker` from Twitter's chill library: https://github.com/twitter/chill#the-meatlocker

Alternatively, the [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) and [algebra](https://github.com/non/algebra) library (has an `Equal` type class similar to the one you use above) have serializable type classes and you should be able to use those like you do above with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that the invocation of `def func2[I: Equal](rdd: RDD[I])` requires some instance of `Equal[I]` in the scope. Since you're using ScalaZ - perhaps it takes the instance from that library, and obviously the instance is not serializable, as reported in the stack trace.

Put your own serializable versions of Equal[I] into scope and that will help.